# Calculate log-likelihood "by hand" for generalized nonlinear least squares regression (nlme)

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, least-squares, nonlinear-regression, mixed-model

I'm trying to calculate the log-likelihood for a generalized nonlinear least squares regression for the function $f(x)=\frac{\beta_1}{(1+\frac x\beta_2)^{\beta_3}}$ optimized by the `gnls` function in the R package `nlme`, using the variance covariance matrix generated by distances on a a phylogenetic tree assuming Brownian motion (`corBrownian(phy=tree)` from the `ape` package). The following reproducible R code fits the gnls model using x,y data and a random tree with 9 taxa:

```
require(ape)
require(nlme)
require(expm)
tree <- rtree(9)
x <- c(0,14.51,32.9,44.41,86.18,136.28,178.21,262.3,521.94)
y <- c(100,93.69,82.09,62.24,32.71,48.4,35.98,15.73,9.71)
data <- data.frame(x,y,row.names=tree$tip.label)
model <- y~beta1/((1+(x/beta2))^beta3)
f=function(beta,x) beta[1]/((1+(x/beta[2]))^beta[3])
start <- c(beta1=103.651004,beta2=119.55067,beta3=1.370105)
correlation <- corBrownian(phy=tree)
fit <- gnls(model=model,data=data,start=start,correlation=correlation)
logLik(fit)
```

I would like to calculate the log-likelihood "by hand" (in R, but without use of the `logLik` function) based on the estimated parameters obtained from `gnls` so it matches the output from `logLik(fit)`. NOTE: I am not trying to estimate parameters; I just want to calculate log-likelihood of the parameters estimated by the `gnls` function (although if someone has a reproducible example of how to estimate parameters without `gnls`, I would be very interested in seeing it!).

I'm not really sure how to go about doing this in R. The linear algebra notation described in Mixed-Effects Models in S and S-Plus (Pinheiro and Bates) is very much over my head and none of my attempts have matched `logLik(fit)`. Here are the details described by Pinheiro and Bates:

The log-likelihood for the generalized nonlinear least squares model  $y_i=f_i(\phi_i,v_i)+\epsilon_i$ where $\phi_i=A_i\beta$ is calculated as follows:

$l(\beta,\sigma^2,\delta|y)=-\frac 12 \Bigl\{ N\log(2\pi\sigma^2)+\sum\limits_{i=1}^M{\Bigl[\frac{||y_i^*-f_i^*(\beta)||^2}{\sigma^2}+\log|\Lambda_i|\Bigl]\Bigl\}}$

where $N$ is the number of observations, and $f_i^*(\beta)=f_i^*(\phi_i,v_i)$.

$\Lambda_i$ is positive-definite, $y_i^*=\Lambda_i^{-T/2}y_i$ and $f_i^*(\phi_i,v_i)=\Lambda_i^{-T/2}f_i(\phi_i,v_i)$

For fixed $\beta$ and $\lambda$, the ML estimator of $\sigma^2$ is

$\hat\sigma(\beta,\lambda)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^M||y_i^*-f_i^*(\beta)||^2 / N$

and the profiled log-likelihood is

$l(\beta,\lambda|y)=-\frac12\Bigl\{N[\log(2\pi/N)+1]+\log\Bigl(\sum\limits_{i=1}^M||y_i^*-f_i^*(\beta)||^2\Bigl)+\sum\limits_{i=1}^M\log|\Lambda_i|\Bigl\}$

which is used with a Gauss-Seidel algorithm to find the ML estimates of $\beta$ and $\lambda$. A less biased estimate of $\sigma^2$ is used:

$\sigma^2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^M\Bigl|\Bigl|\hat\Lambda_i^{-T/2}[y_i-f_i(\hat\beta)]\Bigl|\Bigl|^2/(N-p)$

where $p$ represents the length of $\beta$.

I have compiled a list of specific questions that I am facing:

1. What is $\Lambda_i$? Is it the distance matrix produced by `big_lambda <- vcv.phylo(tree)` in `ape`, or does it need to be somehow transformed or parameterized by $\lambda$, or something else entirely?
2. Would $\sigma^2$ be `fit$sigma^2`, or the equation for the less biased estimate (the last equation in this post)?
3. Is it necessary to use $\lambda$ to calculate log-likelihood, or is that just an intermediate step for parameter estimation? Also, how is $\lambda$ used? Is it a single value or a vector, and is it multiplied by all of $\Lambda_i$ or just off-diagonal elements, etc.?
4. What is $||y-f(\beta)||$? Would that be `norm(y-f(fit$coefficients,x),"F")` in the package `Matrix`? If so, I'm confused about how to calculate the sum $\sum\limits_{i=1}^M||y_i^*-f_i^*(\beta)||^2$, because `norm()` returns a single value, not a vector.
5. How does one calculate $\log|\Lambda_i|$? Is it `log(diag(abs(big_lambda)))` where `big_lambda` is $\Lambda_i$, or is it `logm(abs(big_lambda))` from the package `expm`? If it is `logm()`, how does one take the sum of a matrix (or is it implied that it is just the diagonal elements)?
6. Just to confirm, is $\Lambda_i^{-T/2}$ calculated like this: `t(solve(sqrtm(big_lambda)))`?
7. How are $y_i^*$ and $f_i^*(\beta)$ calculated? Is it either of the following:

`y_star <- t(solve(sqrtm(big_lambda))) %*% y`

and

`f_star <- t(solve(sqrtm(big_lambda))) %*% f(fit$coefficients,x)`

or would it be

`y_star <- t(solve(sqrtm(big_lambda))) * y`

and

`f_star <- t(solve(sqrtm(big_lambda))) * f(fit$coefficients,x)` ?

If all of these questions are answered, in theory, I think the log-likelihood should be calculable to match the output from `logLik(fit)`. Any help on any of these questions would be greatly appreciated. If anything needs clarification, please let me know. Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I have been experimenting with various possibilities for the calculation of the log-likelihood, and here is the best I have come up with so far. `logLik_calc` is consistently about 1 to 3 off from the value returned by `logLik(fit)`. Either I'm close to the actual solution, or this is purely by coincidence. Any thoughts?

```
  C <- vcv.phylo(tree) # variance-covariance matrix
  tC <- t(solve(sqrtm(C))) # C^(-T/2)
  log_C <- log(diag(abs(C))) # log|C|
  N <- length(y)
  y_star <- tC%*%y 
  f_star <- tC%*%f(fit$coefficients,x)
  dif <- y_star-f_star  
  sigma_squared <-  sum(abs(y_star-f_star)^2)/N
  # using fit$sigma^2 also produces a slightly different answer than logLik(fit)
  logLik_calc <- -((N*log(2*pi*(sigma_squared)))+
       sum(((abs(dif)^2)/(sigma_squared))+log_C))/2
```

Comment: your definition of the function $f(x)$ is missing an $x$ on the right hand side.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's start with the simpler case where there is no correlation structure for the residuals:

```
fit <- gnls(model=model,data=data,start=start)
logLik(fit)
```

The log likelihood can then be easily computed by hand with:

```
N <- fit$dims$N
p <- fit$dims$p
sigma <- fit$sigma * sqrt((N-p)/N)
sum(dnorm(y, mean=fitted(fit), sd=sigma, log=TRUE))
```

Since the residuals are independent, we can just use `dnorm(..., log=TRUE)` to get the individual log likelihood terms (and then sum them up). Alternatively, we could use:

```
sum(dnorm(resid(fit), mean=0, sd=sigma, log=TRUE))
```

Note that `fit$sigma` is not the "less biased estimate of $\sigma^2$" -- so we need to make the correction manually first.

Now for the more complicated case where the residuals are correlated:

```
fit <- gnls(model=model,data=data,start=start,correlation=correlation)
logLik(fit)
```

Here, we need to use the multivariate normal distribution. I am sure there is a function for this somewhere, but let's just do this by hand:

```
N <- fit$dims$N
p <- fit$dims$p
yhat <- cbind(fitted(fit))
R <- vcv(tree, cor=TRUE)
sigma <- fit$sigma * sqrt((N-p)/N)
S <- diag(sigma, nrow=nrow(R)) %*% R %*% diag(sigma, nrow=nrow(R))
-1/2 * log(det(S)) - 1/2 * t(y - yhat) %*% solve(S) %*% (y - yhat) - N/2 * log(2*pi)
```

Comment: The log-likelihood for the uncorrelated residuals worked perfectly, however I can't figure out the multivariate normal distribution. In this case, what is S? I tried S <- vcv.phylo(tree) and got approximately -700 for the log-likelihood, whereas logLik(fit) was approximately -33.

Comment: Sorry - I messed up when I copy-pasted the code. Now it is complete. S is the variance-covariance matrix of the residuals. You were on the right track (with the `vcv` function) -- but you need to get the correlation matrix and then use $\hat{\sigma}^2$ to turn this into the var-cov matrix.